# Possible meaning for 'long' in 'not long for this world'

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have come across the phrase 'not long for this world' in many English novels, but it has always struck me as odd, as if a word or part of the sentence were missing. 
I visited numerous websites but all seem to focus on what the phrase means (I knew what the phrase meant already from context in the novels), not its structure, in particular the, in my eyes, odd use of 'long for'.

I am not sure if this is the right place to be asking this particular question, but where does 'long for' come from in this sentence? Is it some archaic use or form of 'belong'?

Thanks for any light you can shed on this!

Comment: Not going to be in this world much longer.  It's not a "longing for" the world, nor is it "belonging to" it, it's a length of time that one will be around.  (Yes, "for", in that context, is a little weird, but it's served the idiom well for 200 years.)

Comment: I may probably be wrong but I interpret the phrase slightly differently. "Not long for this world" as in *my existence in this world is insignificant when compared to how long the World has been in existence.*

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Yes, you are wrong: "He is not long for this world." = "He is about to die [and go to the next world, i.e. heaven.]

Comment: German *belangen, anbelangen* may mean "to matter, concern". A difficult cluster, IMHO. I don't agree that *belong* were a "different beasts", though certainly not the same. Meanwhile, Ger. *gelingen* means "succeed, be succesful".

Answer (score 5):

The expression dates at least as far back as the 18th C., and perhaps even earlier.  It appears to operate on the trope of **long** to a span of time.

It's related to the similarly literary **he is not long in years** (as a way of saying that he is *young*).  To **be long** is to have an abundance of time.

The preposition **for** in the expression echoes the somewhat archaic sense of *destiny*, a sense that persists in the idiom *They're in for it now* (meaning that trouble - usually punishment - awaits them.). It also works on a simpler level, indicating roughly *for the purpose of or usefulness in...*

**To be not long for this world,** then, is to have not many days/hours/moments in store **for** use in the world of the living.

(To **be long,** in this sense, has little to do with **belonging**, which entered the language via the OE *gelaeng* (to accompany, be at hand). **Long**, meanwhile, comes from OE *longe* and shares etymological DNA with German and Dutch *lang.*

The modern pronunciations sound similar, but they're different beasts.)

Comment: I did not come across any reference to this but many thanks for the etymology there - I guess this answers any questions I had about this particular phrase!

Answer (score 3):

According to Online Etymology Dictionary, "[to be not long for this world](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=long)" which means **soon to die** is from 1714:

> The adverb is from Old English *lange*, *longe*, from the adjective. No
>   longer "not as formerly" is from c. 1300; to be not long for this
>   world "soon to die" is from 1714.

In "be not long for this word", *[be long](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/long)* means:

> Take a long time to happen or arrive: '*sit down, tea won't be long*'

As the above example shows, it is usually used in a negative sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Since idioms have a meaning unrelated to the words that make them up,  they don't always follow grammar rules.
What  I think is throwing you off here is word inversion. We sometimes see this in Shakespeare, poetry, or archaic language- "him I hit" instead of "I hit him."

"He's not LONG FOR this world" simply means "He won't remain in this world FOR LONG." It's just been shuffled a bit.

Comment: Whoa. I'd say that '[be] [not] long for something' and 'for [a] long [time]' have _very_ different origins.

Answer (score -1):

I think **for** is the key word here.  It's intended to mean "in consideration of."  The phrase pretty much means that one will not be alive for long.  So, "Not long for this world" is meaning to state a limited time *in consideration of* this state of existence.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+long+for+this+world

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Hill. That was actually one of the sites I visited. Unfortunately, it just explains what the phrase means (and I already knew what it meant, it just remains odd-sounding to me - I will update the question to reflect this), and des does not actually explain the 'long for', or origin of the phrase.

Comment: I don't know... I think the statement makes sense.  Maybe it just sounds funny to you? :)

Comment: Quite possibly, though I wouldn't say that it doesn't make sense to me, it's just that it seems to deviate from grammar rules as I know them, and I'm really looking to understand where the 'long for' comes from, how it fits in that particular sentence, especially because 'long' and 'long for' seem to have no relation to dying or ending (based on the dictionaries I've checked), except for in this phrase.